# Help understanding Unity Profiler time in ms

Tags: unity, profiler

[image: Unity Profiler]

I'm a little confused about this column shown in the picture above.

When it shows 0.22 does it mean "22 miliseconds" or does it mean a fraction of a milisecond (i.e. in this case, around 1/5 of a milisecond) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time is the time taken, *during a single [frame](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16990/what-are-frame-rate-and-fps)*, in milliseconds. `0.22 ms` is `220 microseconds`. For reference, if you want 60 frames per second, you cannot spend more than `1000/60 = 16.67 ms` per frame.

You can click on the graph above to select a specific frame, which is useful to see what happens if you have some lag "spikes", for example when a new player joins the game, or you transition between different screens.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, that was a very detailed answer! (my apologies for taking so long to mark as "accepted", I had forgotten about it and I don't log in frequently!)